# TSQL Maxrecursion on a cte

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I get this error:

> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement
>   completion

when I run this function:

```
    WITH allDays AS (

        SELECT @DateEarly AS date

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, date) as date
        FROM allDays s  
        WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, date) <= @DateLate


   )
    SELECT *
    from allDays 
    where dbo.isFestivo(date)>0
```

I tried to append this option:

```
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200);
```

but i get an error 156 before "option" word.
Do you know why?

Comment: **WHERE EXACTLY** did you *append* this `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 200)` ??? Can you please show us that query you had *with* this option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably putting the option in the wrong place. It needs to be after the where

```
WITH allDays AS (
    SELECT @DateEarly AS date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, date) as date
    FROM allDays s  
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, date) <= @DateLate
)
SELECT *
from allDays 
where dbo.isFestivo(date)>0
option (maxrecursion 200);
```

But try this instead. It'll be quicker...

```
select DATEADD(d, number, @dateearly) as [date]
from master..spt_values 
where type='p'
and number<=datediff(d,@dateearly,@datelate)
and dbo.isFestivo(date)>0
```

Comment: The second one works (but i had to change dbo.isFestivo(date) with dbo.isFestivo(DATEADD(d, number, @dateearly)))!

Comment: The second way is dangerous since `spt_values` undocumented Microsoft stuff that might be deprecated and removed one day...