# Optimize Stored Procedure for calculation of weighted Average

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, stored-procedures, weighted-average

I used following code to calculate weighted Average of products in my accounting application, but when my records increases it raises an error " Maximum Recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" any suggestion for optimization please?

```
   ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductBackAveragePrice]
(
    @InvoiceFK int,@FromDate char(10),@ToDate char(10),@FinancialFK tinyint
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


declare @InvoiceID int=0 , @ProductFK int=0
DECLARE q1_cursor CURSOR Dynamic for select InvoiceFK,ProductFK from Sales.InvoiceDetail where FinancialPeriodFK=@FinancialFK and InvoiceFK=@InvoiceFK
open q1_cursor 
fetch next from q1_cursor into @InvoiceID,@ProductFK

while @@fetch_status=0
begin

with CTE as (
  select RowID,Date,InvoiceID,InvoiceNumber,InvoiceKindFK,[I/O],
    OrderQty, UnitPrice=cast(UnitPrice-(isnull(DiscountAmount,0)/nullif(OrderQty,0)) as decimal),
   cast( OrderQty as decimal) as QuantityOnHand,
    (cast(UnitPrice-(isnull(DiscountAmount,0)/nullif(OrderQty,0)) as decimal)) as AverageUnitCost
    from [dbo].[ProductInOutProduct] (@ProductFK,@FromDate,@ToDate,@FinancialFK)
    where RowId = 1 -- Starting condition for your single product sample data.
  union all
  select R.RowID, R.Date,R.InvoiceID,R.InvoiceNumber,R.InvoiceKindFK, R.[I/O],
    R.OrderQty, case when (R.InvoiceKindFK=3) then CTE.AverageUnitCost else cast(R.UnitPrice-(isnull(R.DiscountAmount,0)/nullif(R.OrderQty,0)) as decimal) end,

      cast(case
      when R.[I/O] = 2 then CTE.QuantityOnHand - R.OrderQty -- Sales don't affect the average unit cost.
      when R.[I/O] = 1 then CTE.QuantityOnHand + R.OrderQty
      else ( CTE.QuantityOnHand) end
         as decimal),

    -- My accounting is pretty rusty, but this should do some sort of useful averaging.
   cast(case
      when (R.[I/O] = 2 or R.InvoiceKindFK=3) then cast(CTE.AverageUnitCost as decimal) -- Sales don't affect the average unit cost.
      else ( CTE.AverageUnitCost * CTE.QuantityOnHand + (R.UnitPrice-(isnull(R.DiscountAmount,0)/nullif(R.OrderQty,0))) * R.OrderQty ) /
        nullif(( CTE.QuantityOnHand + R.OrderQty ),0) end
         as decimal)

    from CTE inner join
      [dbo].[ProductInOutProduct] (@ProductFK,@FromDate,@ToDate,@FinancialFK) as R on R.RowId = CTE.RowID + 1 -- Row by row.
    )

    UPDATE dt
SET dt.BackPrice = dtu.AverageUnitCost
FROM Sales.InvoiceDetail dt
INNER JOIN CTE dtu ON dt.InvoiceFK = dtu.InvoiceID
 WHERE
        dt.FinancialPeriodFK = @FinancialFK and dt.InvoiceFK=dtu.InvoiceID and ProductFK=@ProductFK
option (maxrecursion 0);    



    fetch next from q1_cursor into @InvoiceID,@ProductFK
end
close q1_cursor
deallocate q1_cursor
```

Comment: @PeterSmith As I passed only InvoiceID to cursor so It runs once on cursor

Comment: What is your question actually ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL Maxrecursion on a cte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396388/tsql-maxrecursion-on-a-cte) (and many others)

Comment: @Squirrel when run this SP it raise an error because of huge records ,so please suggest me optimized code

Comment: @EdHarper didn't get what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-write your logic in the SET based instead of CURSOR and update the records in bulk instead of looping through them. It is hard to write it without any tests, but it should look like to something like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductBackAveragePrice]
    (
      @InvoiceFK INT ,
      @FromDate CHAR(10) ,
      @ToDate CHAR(10) ,
      @FinancialFK TINYINT
    )
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;



    WITH    CTE
              AS ( SELECT   RowID ,
                            Date ,
                            InvoiceID ,
                            InvoiceNumber ,
                            InvoiceKindFK ,
                            [I/O] ,
                            OrderQty ,
                            UnitPrice = CAST(UnitPrice
                            - ( ISNULL(DiscountAmount, 0) / NULLIF(OrderQty, 0) ) AS DECIMAL) ,
                            CAST(OrderQty AS DECIMAL) AS QuantityOnHand ,
                            ( CAST(UnitPrice - ( ISNULL(DiscountAmount, 0)
                                                 / NULLIF(OrderQty, 0) ) AS DECIMAL) ) AS AverageUnitCost ,
                            id.ProductFK
                   FROM     Sales.InvoiceDetail id
                            CROSS APPLY [dbo].[ProductInOutProduct](id.ProductFK,
                                                              @FromDate,
                                                              @ToDate,
                                                              @FinancialFK) p
                   WHERE    RowId = 1 -- Starting condition for your single product sample data.
                            AND FinancialPeriodFK = @FinancialFK
                            AND InvoiceFK = @InvoiceFK
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   R.RowID ,
                            R.Date ,
                            R.InvoiceID ,
                            R.InvoiceNumber ,
                            R.InvoiceKindFK ,
                            R.[I/O] ,
                            R.OrderQty ,
                            CASE WHEN ( R.InvoiceKindFK = 3 )
                                 THEN CTE.AverageUnitCost
                                 ELSE CAST(R.UnitPrice
                                      - ( ISNULL(R.DiscountAmount, 0)
                                          / NULLIF(R.OrderQty, 0) ) AS DECIMAL)
                            END ,
                            CAST(CASE WHEN R.[I/O] = 2
                                      THEN CTE.QuantityOnHand - R.OrderQty -- Sales don't affect the average unit cost.
                                      WHEN R.[I/O] = 1
                                      THEN CTE.QuantityOnHand + R.OrderQty
                                      ELSE ( CTE.QuantityOnHand )
                                 END AS DECIMAL) ,

    -- My accounting is pretty rusty, but this should do some sort of useful averaging.
                            CAST(CASE WHEN ( R.[I/O] = 2
                                             OR R.InvoiceKindFK = 3
                                           )
                                      THEN CAST(CTE.AverageUnitCost AS DECIMAL) -- Sales don't affect the average unit cost.
                                      ELSE ( CTE.AverageUnitCost
                                             * CTE.QuantityOnHand
                                             + ( R.UnitPrice
                                                 - ( ISNULL(R.DiscountAmount,
                                                            0)
                                                     / NULLIF(R.OrderQty, 0) ) )
                                             * R.OrderQty )
                                           / NULLIF(( CTE.QuantityOnHand
                                                      + R.OrderQty ), 0)
                                 END AS DECIMAL) ,
                            ProductFK
                   FROM     CTE
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductInOutProduct](ProductFK,
                                                              @FromDate,
                                                              @ToDate,
                                                              @FinancialFK) AS R ON R.RowId = CTE.RowID
                                                              + 1 -- Row by row.
                 )
        UPDATE  dt
        SET     dt.BackPrice = dtu.AverageUnitCost
        FROM    Sales.InvoiceDetail dt
                INNER JOIN CTE dtu ON dt.InvoiceFK = dtu.InvoiceID
        WHERE   dt.FinancialPeriodFK = @FinancialFK
                AND dt.InvoiceFK = dtu.InvoiceID
                AND ProductFK = @ProductFK
        OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 0 );
```